# Add stripe elements multiple publishable keys in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am using React Stripe Elements package. I have two bank accounts in Stripe one for Australia and other for Spain. I want to routes payments to the bank accounts based on the user's location.

i have set a default key of Australian account in env file. i tried to change it using the global stripe object like this window.Stripe("MY_KEY") in componentDidMount method but it does not overwrite the default key when sending request to stripe.

```
defkey = "pk_def_key"
window.Stripe("pk_test_****"); //overwrite default key

this.props.stripe.createToken().then(payload => {
          if (payload.error) {
            this.setState({
              cardError: payload.error.message,
              isLoading: false
            });
            return;
          } else {
            const stripeToken = payload.token.id;
            this.setState({
              data: { ...this.state.data, stripeToken }
            });
            // Do Payment Now
            this.verifyPayment();
          }
        });
```

i expect this.props.stripe to use new key, but it uses default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you might be changing the key dynamically, you would have to initialize Stripe yourself first and then pass it as documented [here](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements#advanced-integrations):

> When one or more of these assumptions doesn't hold true for your integration, you have another option: pass a Stripe instance as the stripe prop to  directly. The stripe prop can be either null or the result of using Stripe(apiKey, options) to construct a Stripe instance.

```
<StripeProvider stripe={stripe}>
  <Checkout />
</StripeProvider>
```

You could even initialize 2 separate instances, one per key and then use the right one depending on the user's location.

Comment: Also add key attribute so that component re-mounts when the key changes. Otherwise without reloading it uses the previous key